# Calling controller methods from a ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to automatically pull ticker data from the Bitfinex bitcoin exchange and put it into a database for a Ruby on Rails project. Right now, I've got a controller *BitfinexesController* that does pull the data and create a new row on the corresponding database table *bitfinexes* when the method *self.create* is called. Right now I'm just trying to write a script that will call that method on a loop. I've tried to do this in the view but keep getting told that that there is an "undefined method 'create' for #".

Am I thinking about this wrong? I've just started learning Ruby on Rails.

Here's the method:

```
def self.create
  newdata ="run script that grabs data"
  @bitfinex = Bitfinex.new(eval(newdata))

  respond_to do |format|
  if @bitfinex.save
    format.html { redirect_to @bitfinex, notice: 'Bitfinex was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bitfinex }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @bitfinex.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end`

Comment: You should move that method to a model, and then u can call that method from anywhere u want.

Comment: "In the view"? In the view you likely have an instance, not the class. Also, `eval`? Are you sure that's necessary?

Comment: I would put this in a module. Then you can call it from both the controller and your script.  I wouldn't recommend calling a controller method from a script.